# Calculating holiday dates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, calculated-columns

I have to create "holiday" table and then create php script so I could show it on my site.

Holidays can be specific, like 15.05.2012 - 15-th of the may.

And non-specific: First(or second, third) sunday of july

Is there any way to create calculated column, so this phrase "First(or second, third) sunday of july", could turn into x.07.2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a calendar table. There is no magic code built into SQL Server that knows when Easter is. This article shows the basic premise - you fill up a table with all the dates from year x to year y, then you update a column called IsHoliday for the dates that are holidays based on specific logic (easiest to do this once, in a loop, then all your code later can refer to the calculated bit):

[ASP Faq reference. The current link no longer works, this is the archive.org cached version of the page](http://web.archive.org/web/20120719141807/http://web.archive.org/web/20070611150639/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-calendar-table.html)

Comment: One additional point: you may want to attach a country field to your calendar table.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus I think this is a company calendar table, not one that needs to hold different sets of holidays for different countries. Or perhaps I misunderstood your point...

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I thought he was *writing* what would become the company table. And a company these days might as well start global, rather than hack it in later.

Answer (score 0):

The link in the answer now takes you to a bogus page that wants to load a virus. Just heads up.

http://codeinet.blogspot.com/2006/08/auxiliary-calendar-table-for-sql.html

This seems to be a working version.